# Multiple file select only returns the last file

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I'm trying to upload images through a multiple `input` tag. buts only returning the last selected file.

```
<input id="input1" name="img_1[]" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple" required />
```

When I try to get this File array on server size it returns the value of the last file select.

```
$file = $request->file('img_1');
foreach($file as $f){
...
```

Even when I try to check the value in the console it shows the value of the last selected file. Can someone Kindly tell, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: please post relevant HTML code (the form) and relevant PHP code also

Comment: try to dd the $request->all() and check what's inside

Comment: @Akam i have posted the input tag which is being used. the whole is too large to post here. also, I'm using laravel so i have posted the laravel code.

Comment: I did, I'm getting only the last select image for the file part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple reasons : 
1 - You may have forgot to add enctype="multipart/form-data" to your form.
2 - Did you tried to loop on your array, or uploading it with indexes :

```
$files = Request::file('img_1');
die ($files[0]);
```

Comment: also I'm using multipart/form-data

Comment: i inderstand from your comments that the HTML code is large, so i ask you to share with us the result of var_dump on your $file variable